# TypeError: writelines() requires an iterable argument

Tags: python, syntax, arguments, iterable

I was making an simple script which finds the admin panel of a website. 
I was able to do this with command line interface, but i also wanted to make a simple gui using easygui. 
 
I have hours doing it, but i get this error on line 33: 
'TypeError: writelines requires an iterable argument'

Here is my code:

```
import os, httplib
import easygui as eg

admpagelist = ['admin/','administrator/','admin1/','admin2/']

title = 'Test Easygui'
msg='Enter Your Target: (without http://) '
value = []
value = eg.enterbox(msg,title)
value = value.replace('Enter Your Target: (without http:// )','')

collectornf = []
collectorf = []

try:
    con = httplib.HTTPConnection(value)
    con.connect()
except:
    eg.msgbox('Host is offline or invalid url! ')

for adm in admpagelist:
    adm = '/%s' %adm
    host = value + adm
    con = httplib.HTTPConnection(value)
    con.connect()
    request = con.request('GET',adm)
    response = con.getresponse()
    if response.status == 200:
        collectorf = collectorf.append(str(host))
        found = open('C:/Users/Andi/Desktop/found.txt','w')
        found.writelines(collectorf)
        found.close()
    else:
        collectornf = collectornf.append(str(host))
        notfound = open('C:/Users/Andi/Desktop/notfound.txt','w')
        notfound.writelines(collectornf)
        notfound.close()
```

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the answer, instead of linking to it, and please give the *full* exception and stack trace.

Comment: Also note that when working with files in Python, you should always use [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4). You should also always catch *explicit* exceptions. Using `except:` means all exceptions will be caught, masking problems and making things harder to debug. Only catch exact exceptions you know will come up and know how to handle, using `except SomeExplicitException:`.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that you do `collectorf = collectorf.append(str(host))`.

`list.append()` modifies the list in-place, and returns `None`. You are then assigning that `None` value and overwriting the list.

Just do `collectorf.append(str(host))` instead:

```
if response.status == 200:
    filename = "found.txt"
    data = collectorf
else:
    filename = "notfound.txt"
    data = collectornf
data.append(str(host))
with open('C:/Users/Andi/Desktop/' + filename,'w') as found:
    found.writelines(data)
```

(Refactored to avoid copy/paste coding and use some of the advice I posted as comments).

Note that it would make a lot more sense to write the data after the loop, not repeatedly during it.

Comment: thanks for your answer but there is one thing.
In my program i need to be appeared the found and not found admin pages. So with the code you gave me, my program would give a list of all of the tried admin pages, but the user would'nt which one is found and which is not

Comment: My code appends them to either `collectornf` or `collectorf` depending on if the response is 200 or not, just like your code. I don't see what your issue is?

Comment: Just a misunderstanding by my side!
Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the files open. COnstantly opening and closing them seems a lot of overhead to me.

```
with open('C:/Users/Andi/Desktop/found.txt','w') as found, open('C:/Users/Andi/Desktop/notfound.txt','w') as notfound: # before 2.7, write this as 2 with statements
    for adm in admpagelist:
        adm = '/%s' % adm
        host = value + adm
        con = httplib.HTTPConnection(value)
        con.connect()
        request = con.request('GET', adm)
        response = con.getresponse()
        if response.status == 200:
            targetlist = collectorf
            targetfile = found
        else:
            targetlist = collectornf
            targetfile = notfound
        targetlist.append(str(host))
        targetfile.write(str(host) + '\n')
        # if you are paranoid, you can as well do:
        # targetfile.flush()
```

The `with` stuff is responsible for closing the file afterwards again.

If you don't need the lists afterwards, you can omit them, as we write into the files in each loop run.

Comment: Yeah , have to try that too!
Thanks. By the way anyway to write in these files in newlines.
I mean:
website.com/admin
website.com/admin2 etc...
Cause in found and not found.txt these are not written in newline.
Maybe i should make a for loop like this:

for i in targetlist:
    i = '%s\n' %i

Comment: @WidexND Forgot about that and edited my solution: if you want it to have newlines, just put them wherever you want them to be: after each entry in the files: `targetfile.write(str(host) + '\n')`

Comment: thank you for your help!
I had never heard with statement before, so i also learnt something new